# What specifies the agreement (i.e. the convention) of which registers are used to pass which arguments and to return which values?

Tags: assembly, calling-conventions

In Computer Systems: a Programmer's Perspective:

> procedure calls may involve
> passing data as arguments, and returning from a procedure may also
> involve returning a value. With x86-64, most of these data passing to
> and from procedures take place via registers. For example, we have
> already seen numerous examples of functions where arguments are passed
> in registers %rdi, %rsi, and others, and where values are re- turned
> in register %rax. When procedure P calls procedure Q, the code for P
> must ﬁrst copy the arguments into the proper registers. Similarly,
> when Q returns back to P, the code for P can access the returned value
> in register %rax. In this section, we explore these **conventions** in
> greater detail.

> [image]

Is it correct that a caller and its callee procedure must agree on which registers to be used to pass which arguments and which registers to be used to return which values?

What specifies this agreement?

- The procedure to be called (so different procedures specify different agreement which callers must agree on?)
- The assembly language (so different assembly languages specify different agreement which procedures and callers must agree on?)
- The machine language (ISA)  (so different machine languages specify different agreement which procedures and callers must agree on?) ?

What specifies the particular convention in the example and the figure in the quote?

Comment: A [Calling Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) is part of the [Application Binary Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).  They are both machine/processor and operating environment specific.

Answer (score 1):

> The procedure to be called (so different procedures specify different agreement which callers must agree on?)

In general, yes - and if you're programming in a vacuum without ever needing to interoperate with anybody else's code (including the operating system), then that's all you need to know.

However, most of us don't write code in a vacuum (some embedded programming might count), so there are a [number of conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) which have been agreed so that code compiled with different compilers can interoperate.